# Which hook/action will help me solve my problem?

Tags: php, posts

I want to add my first post of current date to drafts and when the second post is added, I want both of them to be published together. Below is my code and I am confused on how to post them in draft and publish them accordingly

```
function gk_post_status(){

$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$day = date("d");
$posts = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        'year'  => $year,
        'month' => $month,
        'day'   => $day,
    ));

$the_query = new WP_Query( $posts );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ){
    //Publish both posts when clicked on "Publish"
}else{
    //Save post in draft when clicked on "Publish"
}

}
add_action( 'init', 'gk_post_status' );
```